# Open file with command-line program

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to open a .py file with Python in a terminal every time a file is double-clicked in a GUI file manager, like in Windows. How would I go about doing this?

For Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: @wilf I'm just looking for how to do this for .py files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Unity & Gnome, similar things are there for other desktop environments.

Right click on the file, and go to <kbd>Properties</kbd>, and permissions. Make sure this is ticked :

[image: Execute - TICK Allow executing file as program] 
<sup>*(You need this ticked anyway for the file to run in terminal, or be 'executed', it is the same as running `chmod +x /PATH/TO/FILE`)*</sup>

And make sure this,  under the <kbd>Behaviour</kbd> tab, in Nautilus file manager's preferences, is set to this:
[image: Executable Text Files - Ask Each Time]

Now every time you click on it, you should get:

[image: Do you want to run EXAMPLE.py, or show its contents - buttons]

<kbd>Run in Terminal</kbd>, you can guess.
 <kbd>Display</kbd> opens it in the default text editor defined in 'Open With...'. in the files preferences.
 <kbd>Run</kbd> runs it in the background, with no terminal. This is also what happens if you select 'Run executable text files when they are opened' above.

---

Here is a fix to stop it closing instantly - go to <kbd>Profile Preferences</kbd>,  and under <kbd>Title and Command</kbd>, set:

[image: 'When the command exits' to 'Hold the terminal open'], Now when you run a script like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
print "Hello"
time.sleep(5)
print "Goodbye"
```

<sup>*(Remember the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` line, otherwise it won't be interpreted correctly. You can also use `#!/usr/bin/env python`.)*</sup>

It stay open a while, then you should get something like:
[image]

Comment: This treats the Python files as Shell scripts, so the terminal opens, but when it goes to read the Python code, it runs into errors and closes the terminal instantly. Upvote for the detailed answer anyway.

Comment: You need to include the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line as the first line, so that the interpreter can work out that it is a python script, and runs it as python. Updated answer.

Comment: Bingo! I've been leaving the shebang out of my code lately, and that ended up being the problem. Thanks!

Comment: He should also be able to use ./pythonfile.py from the terminal.

Comment: @owl, yes if the file is in the current directory *(in terminal)*, and called `pythonfile.py`, and has executable permissions - but that is not what the OP asked ;). **Sil** My problem is I nearly always forget, or miss out the `!`! :D